# Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Writer error when saving a product in osCommerce

Tags: php, oscommerce, zend-search-lucene

I am receiving the following error when saving a product in osCommerce.  The script has been modified to index the product in a Lucene index.  This error only occurs intermittently, ie. I can resave the product and it gets indexed correctly, while at other times it throws the error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Writer::__construct() 
must be an instance of Zend_Search_Lucene_Storage_Directory, null given, called in 
/var/www/vhosts/mtr/public_html/mastervault/Zend/Search/Lucene.php on line 645 
and defined in 
/var/www/vhosts/mtr/public_html/mastervault/Zend/Search/Lucene/Index/Writer.php on line 223
```

Any ideas as to how this could throw such an error intermittently, running the same script posting exactly the same data?  I can try to save my data once and it will throw the error, then save again and it indexes the product correctly without error.

Comment: It's pretty clear what the error message is telling you if you read it, so what are you asking?

Comment: Clear to you it may be Devon, if so, then why don't you enlighten me? It is not at all clear to me why this error is being thrown, particularly since it's intermittent, running exactly the same script posting exactly the same data - one time it works, another it does not.  Perhaps you can explain that, but I cannot.

Comment: Ok Devon, you just want to play dumb.... just go and play somewhere else to get your thrills.

Comment: Oh for crying out loud Devon.  Clearly the question is:  Any ideas as to why it's throwing this intermittent error when running the same script posting exactly the same data?

Comment: Right Devon.  So you get your thrills by harassing people on the internet.  It's quite possible that somebody has seen the exception that I posted and for them that would be quite enough to give an answer.  I am certain that you yourself know nothing whatsoever about Zend Lucene, and probably anything else to do with programming.  But no, we have to put up with jerks like you who have nothing better to do.

Comment: Billy, grow up and learn how to use the site.  I edited the question to make it more relevant to the areas you are posting in.  It is a not a PHP question since there is no PHP code included.  Maybe someone following the oscommerce tag can provide some more insight.

Comment: As I expected Devon, you know nothing whatsoever about the topic at hand.  Zend Lucene is indeed PHP, as is osCommerce, so please put back the PHP tag.  Then trot off and harass somebody else and grow up yourself.

Comment: It's an oscommerce and zend lucene question since you didn't include any PHP code which is why I removed the PHP tag.  If you had included the PHP code that caused the error, then it would have been on-topic for php.  I'm not harassing, if anything I was trying to guide you to an on-topic question so your question would get help without being downvoted / put on hold.

Comment: Devon, trust me, this is PHP:  Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Writer::__construct()